# Can I use same row data in one query?

Tags: sql, database, join, count

I have table like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64jR6.png)

From this, I want to fetch database and want to find per user frequency of Action like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnwng.png)

Please help me find find suitable query for this.

I tried queries like below. But I want to merge both query in single one.

```
PrepareStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("Select distinct Action, User_Id from TABLE_NAME");
ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery();

while(rs1.next()){

PrepareStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("Select count(Action) from TABLE_NAME where User_Id=? AND Action=?");
ps2.setString(1,rs1.getString("User_Id"));
ps2.setString(2,rs1.getString("Action"));

ResultSet rs2=ps2.executeQuery();

System.out.println(rs1.getString("User_Id")+" "+rs1.getString("Action")+" "+rs2.getString("Action"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which RDBMS are you using? The exact SQL may/will vary depending on the database/version combination.

A generic answer to this would be:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  action,
  count(action) as frequency
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  user_id, action
```

CAVEAT: I have tried this in a database - so YMMV.

Comment: This will give a total count of action. I want count per user for one action.